# Isn't Azure oid from auth callback unique? Azure active directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Auth with Azure:

```
const authConfig = {
  clientID,
  clientSecret,
  callbackURL: `${baseUrl}/api/login/callback`,
  tenant: "xxx.onmicrosoft.com",
  useCommonEndpoint: false
};

const callback = async (accessToken, _: string, params, profile, done) => {
  const waadProfile: IAzureUser = jwt.decode(
    params.id_token,
    process.env.AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET
  );
 // Check if user exists in local db
 const user = await mongoose
   .model("user")
  .findOne({ azureOid: waadProfile.oid  })
  .exec();
 // Create user in local db if not found..
 ....
```

I assumed the `oid` was fixed and would not change for a user.

Now I can see in my app a duplicate user has been created since the `oid` differs.

Why have the `oid` suddenly changed for a user? Is it just random or has the IT department done something that have generated a new `oid` for this specific user?

Answer (score 1):

One of several things are possible:

1. The user signed in through a different AAD tenant (a user has a different object id in each tenant)
2. The user was deleted and re-created (gets a new object id)

An object id for a user is immutable and cannot change.

Comment: "A different AAD tenant". What does it mean? How can a user use another "AAD tenant"? He used another device?

Comment: That one is only possible if your app is multi-tenant :) I.e. if it allows logging in from many organizations. A user can be invited to another AAD organization (tenant) right? They get a unique id in each organization where they are a member of. This is a bit of a corner case that may not be the case for you.

Comment: I've updated the question with the authconfig. The app is not multitenant. Bug in Azure?

Comment: Yeah it's not multi-tenant. How about the second option? Could the user have been re-created?

Comment: I'll check with the user. Seems far fetched though. I accept the answer if that would be the case. Thanks.